# Purging RBENV completely not working

Tags: ruby, rbenv

How do I remove rbenv completely from my system?

I've tried running these 4 commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove  rbenv
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove rbenv
sudo apt-get purge rbenv
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rbenv
```

And then when I run `rbenv -v` I get the below line. :\

```
rbenv 1.0.0-33-gc7dcaf1
```

How do I remove it? Its conflicting with rvm.

Comment: Have you restart the terminal after purge command?

Comment: Yes I did. Even restarted the laptop. Im using ubuntu. if it helps in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a copy of rbenv installed in your PATH somewhere that's not managed by apt-get. I'd start by finding where rbenv is installed with:

```
$ type rbenv
```

From there you can either try to uninstall the extraneous version or change the PATH environment variable so that it doesn't pick up rbenv.

(I've never used RVM, so I don't know exactly what the problem is with having rbenv installed. Maybe there's a more direct solution?)

Comment: I removed the ~/.rbenv file and all the rbenv reference lines in ~/.bashrc file. It worked.